# Bash string substitution with %

Tags: bash, variables

I have a list of files named with this format:

```
S2_7-CHX-2-5_Chr5.bed
S2_7-CHX-2-13_Chr27.bed
S2_7-CHX-2-0_Chr1.bed
```

I need to loop through each file to perform a task. Previously, I had named them without the step 2 indicator ("S2"), and this format had worked perfectly:

```
for FASTQ in *_clean.bam; do
  SAMPLE=${FASTQ%_clean.bam}
  echo $SAMPLE
  echo $(samtools view -c ${SAMPLE}_clean.bam)
done
```

But now that I have the S2 preceding what I would like to set as the variable, this returns a list of empty "SAMPLE" variables. How can I rewrite the following code to specify only S2_*.bed?

```
for FASTQ in S2_*.bed; do
  SAMPLE=${S2_FASTQ%.bed}
  echo $SAMPLE
done
```

Edit: I'm trying to isolate the unique name from each file, for example "7-CHX-2-13_Chr27" so that I can refer to it later. I can't use the "S2" as part of this because I want to rename the file with "S3" for the next step, and so on.

Example of what I'm trying to use it for:

```
for FASTQ in S2_*.bed; do
  SAMPLE=${S2_FASTQ%.bed}
  echo $SAMPLE
  #rename each mapping position with UCSC chromosome name using sed
  while IFS=, read -r f1 f2; do
    #rename each file
    echo "  sed "s/${f1}.1/chr${f2}/g" S2_${SAMPLE}_Chr${f2}.bed > S3_${SAMPLE}_Chr${f2}.bed" >> $SCRIPT
  done < $INPUT
done
```

Comment: What output do you expect? `7-CHX-2-5_Chr5` etc.?

Comment: it should be `SAMPLE="${FASTQ%.bed}"`

Comment: BTW, in `echo $(samtools view -c ${SAMPLE}_clean.bam)` the `echo` and `$( )` basically cancel each other out. It's almost always better to omit both, and just run `samtools view -c ${SAMPLE}_clean.bam` without the extra mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the variable is still $FASTQ, the S2_ is not part of the variable name, but its value.

```
sample=${FASTQ%.bed}
#        ~~~~~|~~~~
#          |  |  |
#    Variable |  What to remove
#     name    |
#           Remove
#        from the right
```

If you want to remove the S2_ from the $sample, use left hand side removal:

```
sample=${sample#S2_}
```

The removals can't be combined, you have to proceed in two steps.

Note that I use lower case variable names. Upper case should be reserved for environment and internal shell variables.

Comment: I'm not trying to remove anything, I'm just trying to isolate the unique sample name ("7-CHX-2-13_Chr27") from each file so that I can refer to it later

Comment: @Sarah: Yes, but to isolate it, you need to remove the prefix (S2_) and suffix (.bed). The original variable will stay intact, the new one will contain the desired string.